# locate stop/diagonal matrix pattern

Tags: r

I  have a binary coded matrix (0/1)matrix that looks like this:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1  0  0  1
2   0  0  0  0
3   0  0  0  0
4   1  1  1  0
5   1  1  0  0
6   0  0  1  0
7   1  0  1  0
8   0  0  1  0
9   0  0  1  0
10  0  0  0  0
11  1  1  0  0
12  0  0  0  1
13  0  0  0  1
14  0  0  0  1
15  0  0  0  0
16  0  1  1  0
17  1  1  0  0
18  1  0  1  0
19  1  0  1  0
20  1  1  1  1
```

I'm looking to detect a pattern that I can determine visually and describe but can't come up with a programmatic search to find that pattern.  Here's the pattern:

I want to locate end of runs of the number 1 that stop and are picked up in the next row by a different column (so a diagonal switch if the columns happened to be side by side).  If another column would have kept this run of 1s going the diagonal switch does not count.

So in the matrix above the diagonal switch happens at x[5, 2] to x[6, 3] and again at x[11, 1 (or 2)] to x[12, 4]

```
x <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), X4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("X1", 
    "X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is kind of a difficult problem to describe but I think I've used the example to illustrate it.  The desired output would be `c(5, 11)` because those are the rows when the 1's have this pattern.

I suspect `rle` and `cumsum` may be of use here.

**Edit** To add info to the problem.  I tried Ricardo's initial solution on a different matrix:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   0  0  1  0  0
2   1  1  0  0  1
3   0  0  0  0  0
4   0  0  1  0  0
5   0  1  1  0  0
6   1  0  1  1  0
7   1  1  0  0  0
8   0  0  1  1  1
9   0  0  1  0  0
10  1  1  0  1  0

rowdiffs <- apply(D, 2, diff)

N  <- rowSums(rowdiffs==-1)
P  <- rowSums(rowdiffs==1)

which(N - P > 0 &  P > 0)
```

It gives:

```
## 7 
## 6
```

I would expect `c(1, 7, 9)` as can be seen in the line a traced here.  At each red dot I had no choice but to go diagonal (these are the blue paths).  If I reach a row of all 0's (the yellow box) I skip that row and start over with the path (path is orange) on the next row (and no diagonal pattern is recorded)

[image]

```
D <- structure(list(X1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
        X2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X3 = c(1L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X5 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't follow "If another column would have kept this run of 1s going"...

Comment: Maybe if you clarified the exclusions...seems like 7, 17, 19 should be there.

Comment: Why are rows  `16` & `17` not candidates?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Not a candidate because column 2 carries the run of 1s through to 17.  Then we can move horizontal on row 17 and move to column 1 where a new run of 1s occurs.  But the main thing is this has to happen at the end of a run of 1s and row 17 is the end but if you can move horizontally to a new run it's not a diagonal jump.  I know thos is difficult to explain (understand too) but I think the example will help use understand the rules that govern the pattern.

Comment: @Frank not row 7 because there's a column of 1s being carried through by column 3.

Comment: @TylerRinker Starting to make sense.  What exactly constitutes a `run`? Horizontal, vertical?  (I assume vertical).  And also, why then is `11` included?  A single row counts as a run?

Comment: So the upper element of the diagonal pair must have zeros to the right and a zero immediately below it? I guess there's something more, because that still means [17,2] & [18,3] work...

Comment: @RicardoSaporta a run is one or more in a column.  So 11 has a run of one.  We can move to column 1 (because there's an adjacent 1 there) but it does us no good because the 1's do no continue down column 1.  However, the column 4 in the next row does have a 1 so if column 2 and 4 had been next to each other there'd have been a diagonal jump with no way to move left/right and then continue a downward run.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft good catch.  Forgot to change this.  See the comment below Ricardo's answer for more of why, but yes the desired output of the second matrix is `c(1, 7, 9)`.

Comment: @TylerRinker then just check my edited answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
rowdiffs <- rbind(apply(D, 2, diff), NA)

N  <- rowSums(rowdiffs==-1)
P  <- rowSums(rowdiffs==1)

candidates <- which(N &  P)
falseCandidates <- which(rowSums(rowdiffs==0 & D==1) >= 1)

setdiff(candidates, falseCandidates)
#  [1] 1 7 9
```

---

#### Explanation:

Compare each row with the one below it (`rowdiffs`).
The candidate rows will have the following properties:

```
* contain both a `-1` and `+1` in the diffs 
      (indicating the diagonal move)
* NOT contain a `0` in the diffs where there is a `1` in the original data
      (indicating potential lateral move (or standard straight down))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried a new matrix as seen above.  It does not work as expected (I think this new case will further illustrate the pattern).

Comment: @TylerRinker, I like the illustrative diagram!! hahah, lets have a look :)

Comment: This is complicated and the digraph was the only means I could do it.  Words were difficult here. :)

Comment: @TylerRinker In the new one, is `row 3` included because it is all zeros, or because `row 4` has a `1` in `X3`?

Comment: @ Ricardo I had typed this out and then changed to cover corner cases.  Originally I said expectations were `c(1, 3, 4, 7, 9)` but with the new changes to cover corner cases the expectations are `c(1, 7, 9)`.  I just forgot to change that and caught it later but not before you saw it.

Comment: @tyler, see the edit.  Tested on both of the sets provided and seems to work

Comment: Both you and @Ferdinand.kraft have answered with exactly what I'm after.  Bench marks showed this was the faster way and thus the check.  Thank you both for your work.

Comment: Glad it helped.  @Ferdinand.kraft's answer is very slick as well

Answer (score 1):

The dotted rows in your diagram (1,7,9) can be found with this:

```
trans <- apply(D, 2, function(x) head(x,-1)*10+tail(x,-1))

which(apply(trans, 1, function(y) (1 %in% y) && (10 %in% y) && !(11 %in% y) ))

#1 7 9
```

Explanation: first build a matrix of transitions then find rows where both transitions from 0 to 1 and from 1 to zero occurs, but no continuity of ones appears.

Comment: I think this does it.  I have to go to bed and can't test on multiple instances of the actual data yet tonight.  I'll investigate further tomorrow.  I suspect you used sorcery in this answer :)

Comment: @TylerRinker BTW, with your first input (`x`), the new answer gives `c(5,11)` also.

Comment: Yeah I checked it and both solutions work identical against multiple data sets.  Very clever and almost magical :)